# Maya Python: call name from textfield in other window?

Tags: python, maya

Ok, so I have 2 scripts and what I want them to do are simple. In DS_testShapeNamer I want the user to be able to select a side and type the name of the shape into the textfield: then open DS_testShapeBuilder, hit "build demo shape" and create a shape with the name lf_textFieldNameYouEntered.

If I figure this trick out I can trim down alot of the fat in my other rigging scripts instead of having to add matching gui elements to my new scripts, I can just call it from one gui in the base script.

Running the scripts is very easy:

01.) create 2 python files in c:\Users\userName\Documents\maya\2020\scripts, name them DS_testShapeNamer.py and DS_testShapeBuilder.py respectively

02.) copy and paste the following code into DS_testShapeNamer.py

```
'''
import DS_testWindowName
reload (DS_testWindowName)
DS_testWindowName.gui()
'''
import maya.cmds as cmds

if cmds.window("nameWin", exists =True):
    cmds.deleteUI("nameWin", window = True)

myWindow = cmds.window("nameWin",t='DS_testShapeNamer',rtf=1,w=100, h=100, toolbox=True)
column = cmds.columnLayout(adj=True)

def gui(*args):
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

    cmds.rowColumnLayout( numberOfRows=1 )

    cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns = 3,adjustableColumn=2)
    cmds.optionMenu('sidePref',label='Select Side       ',w=168)
    cmds.menuItem( label='lf' )
    cmds.menuItem( label='rt' )
    cmds.menuItem( label='ct' )
    cmds.text(l='IncPref')
    cmds.textField('incText',it = '_testShapeName',editable=True)
    cmds.setParent('..')
    
    cmds.showWindow(myWindow)
```

03.) copy and paste the following code into DS_testShapeBuilder.py

```
'''
import DS_testWindowShape
reload (DS_testWindowShape)
DS_testWindowShape.gui()
'''
import maya.cmds as cmds

if cmds.window("buildWin", exists =True):
    cmds.deleteUI("buildWin", window = True)

myWindow = cmds.window("buildWin",t='DS_testShapeBuilder',rtf=1,w=100, h=100, toolbox=True)
column = cmds.columnLayout(adj=True)

def gui(*args):
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)
    cmds.button(w=300,label='build demo shape',c=buildShapes)
    cmds.showWindow(myWindow)
    
def buildShapes(*args):
    sidePref = DS_testWindowName.gui() #I need to create a variable that calls the name from the other window
    namePref = 'bob'
    cmds.sphere(n= sidePref + namePref)
```

04.) create a new python tab in the maya script editor and paste the following:

```
import DS_testWindowName
reload (DS_testWindowName)
DS_testWindowName.gui()
```

and

```
import DS_testWindowShape
reload (DS_testWindowShape)
DS_testWindowShape.gui()
```

05.) highlight the script you pasted and hit enter on the numpad to run the scripts

06.) in DS_testShapeNamer, select a side and type in any name in the textfield

07.) DS_testShapeBuilder, hit "build demo shape"

My goal is to figure out how to link the option menu and the textfield in DS_testShapeNamer to DS_testShapeBuilder's "build demo shape"

My apologies if this this is a relatively simple question: but my python ability is mostly self taught and any help is appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is there a special reason why you use two files which create UI elements? It would simplify the things a lot if you have only one file.

Comment: The big reason is  my auto rigging tools all have the same gui pasted into them. So If i wanted to build an arm I would need to select the side I want to work on, then the increment of that limb: and I would need to set those same settings for every new tool I open: but it i can tie it to one parent script with the settings i want, I can save my self some work instead of having to punch in the same settings every time I open a new tool.

Comment: Still don't understand your logic. But in maya you always have the problem that UI scripts are called idependently from other scripts, e.g. if you create a window with a button, the buttonscript itself does not know anything about the UI, you have to feed any data you need into the button script. In mel this is done by global functions what is not the best way to solve this problem. In python you can use classes to encapsulate everything and keep all data for easy access in the class and the UI is part of the class.